# Is separating design from implementation a net win?

Tags: design, development-process

In my experience, technical design is made more challenging when it is divorced  from implementation, particularly by assigning the roles to different people, because its easy for the designer to overlook a myriad of implementation details/gotchas. In theory, I like the idea though. So my question is, should we be striving for this separation?

Comment: Not sure what technologies you're working with, but the short answer is yes.

Comment: You need the design to know how to implement, just as you need to know implementation restrictions to know how to design. So there should definitely be some overlap in communication there. As far as actual implementation goes though, write your code in a way that makes sense from the technical perspective, not that makes sense from the design perspective. UI design can change, and this makes it easy to update just the UI, or vice versa.

Comment: What kind of design are you referring to: UI design or software/code design (designing the architecture)?

Comment: @Murphy mainly software/code design

Comment: In this case I'm with the "it isn't" gang.

Comment: Your whole question does not refer to software development, there is nothing which indicates that. Moreover, if it is about software development, you have to more precise about what you understand by "design", and what by "implementation". For me, implementation is what a compiler does, design is an activity what people do manually (which includes coding).  If that is your point of view, too, then the answer is clearly yes: there was a big win by letting do the implementation (=compiling) by fully automatic programs (called compilers).

Answer (score 5):

No, the separation is not a net win. In fact, separating design decisions from the act of writing the code is probably going to cause more pain for a project.

It seems to me like you're using "implementation" to refer to the act of writing code. In a sequential process, like a traditional Waterfall, the end of "design" is a set of artifacts that fully describe the software that needs to be implemented. In this environment, you may have a design team and an implementation team. If the individuals are different, I would agree that you are right - it's easy to overlook "implementation" (code, build, deploy) level issues when doing design. Unless you fully know the environment - the hardware, the operating system and third-party packages available, the programming language used - it's almost impossible to come up with a "final" design by a disjoint design team.

If you look at software development through the lens of [Lean Software Development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lean_software_development), there are problems with this disjoint viewing of design and implementation. First, it's wasteful. Motion (moving information between teams), waiting (coders waiting for designers to finish), and management activities (needed to coordinate these two teams) are all considered waste. Second, it prevents learning, especially if the coders are not able to modify and update the design artifacts and need to go back to the design team. Third, it prevents deciding late. Fourth, it prevents seeing the whole as elements of the design may be ideal on paper but unrealistic knowing the details of the environment.

This is a primary reason why the agile methods emphasize cross-functional teams.

However, there is another method to look at things.

I define "requirements engineering" (or a similar term, like "requirements development") as the activities associated with understanding the users, the environment, and what the system or software must do, along with mandatory or desired quality attributes. I define "design" as the activities that lead to creating something that meets the requirements. I subscribe to the belief that [code is design](http://www.developerdotstar.com/mag/articles/reeves_design_main.html). "Implementation" is what is done by computers - using various tools and scripts to compile (if necessary), package, and deploy software to a form that can be accessed by the user.

This view fits much nicer into the Lean Software Development and agile methods view of the world. Plus, it actually makes software development map a little closer to other engineering disciplines.

Answer (score 3):

There is no clear cut between technical design and implementation.

Just think of the following activities and try to decide if it is a designer's work:

- Define classes
- Decide what messaging mechanism to use
- Decide what type of control structures to use
- Decide what data structures to use
- Decide how to divide the code to different functions
- Define database queries

and so on...

No matter where you'll cut it, the 'implementation' will still include 'technical design'.

Some [experienced] people can better tackle 'big' architecture questions, while other [experienced as well] can better tackle more detailed issues. Nevertheless, no one just 'implement'.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're working on mission critical systems in things like flight control systems, Mars rovers, or human life support systems, you'd probably make a lot more work for yourselves by trying to completely separate these roles.

Do whatever gets the job done in a reasonably testable and maintainable way, don't make it too hard on yourselves.  Something working "good enough" is generally a lot better than the perfect solution never completed.